# JavaScript - Game. Algorithm to match two variables generate by random generator

Tags: javascript, html, css, random

I have problem with my algorithm in simple game.

Game Rules:
Match color NAME (choose one on the bottom) with COLOR of TEXT (on the top).
If none of the two bottom names match than click NEXT.

So the problem is that first correct match gives in console "GOOD" but second , third and any after, even if there is correct match in console I have firstly always "WRONG" and just after that I have "GOOD".

---

### [This is a picture with the problem described](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCMb3.png)

It seems like the script remember past random numbers and match current result with them, because after few matches the score pointer raise very quickly (ex. 20 points in one time).

I will be happy to hear from you how can I fix this.
Thank you for any help !

Here you have link to codepen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bWGGga

```js
"use strict"


/*Start Container*/
/* var startContainer = document.getElementById("start_container");
var letsPlay = document.getElementById("start_game"); */
/* letsPlay.addEventListener("click", openTheGame); */


function openTheGame(){
    setInterval(startGame, 3000);
};

openTheGame();


var btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1");
var btn2 = document.getElementById("btn2");
var btn3 = document.getElementById("btn3");

var showColor = document.getElementById("show_color");

//SCORE
var score = document.getElementById("score");




var gameContainer = document.getElementById("game_container");
var gameOverContainer = document.getElementById("game_over_container");

/*Array of Colors*/

var arrCol = ["GREEN", "RED", "YELLOW", "BLUE", "ORANGE", "PURPLE"]


//Array from buttons texts to draw Show Color
var arrShowColor = [];

function startGame(){
    



/*BUTTONS TEXT & COLOR*/



btn1.addEventListener("click", matchColor1);
btn2.addEventListener("click", matchColor2);
btn3.addEventListener("click", matchColor3);

    
    
    //draw numbers for buttons texts & colors
var randomBtn1Num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3); 
var randomBtn2Num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)+3; 
var randomBtn3Num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6); 


    //Buttons text (next button always "next")
btn1.innerHTML = arrCol[randomBtn1Num];
btn2.innerHTML = arrCol[randomBtn2Num];

    //Buttons Color from random_color class
btn1.className = "random_color" + randomBtn2Num;
btn2.className = "random_color" + randomBtn3Num;
btn3.className = "random_color" + randomBtn1Num;
    
    
/*SHOW TEXT & COLOR*/
    
    //Array from buttons texts to draw Show Color


arrShowColor[0] = randomBtn1Num;
arrShowColor[1] = randomBtn2Num;
arrShowColor[2] = randomBtn3Num;

console.log(arrShowColor);
    
    //Show color
var randomShowColorNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
var randomShowColor = arrShowColor[randomShowColorNum];
    
showColor.className = "random_color" + randomShowColor; 
    
console.log(randomShowColor);
    
    //Show text
    var randomShowText = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6); 
    showColor.innerHTML = arrCol[randomShowText];

    
/*CLICK BUTTON - IF MATCH COLORS*/

function matchColor1(){
  
    if( randomBtn1Num == randomShowColor) {
            
        console.log("GOOD");
      
         score.innerHTML ++;
        
    } else {
        console.log("WRONG");
        /*gameContainer.style.display = "none";
        gameOverContainer.style.display = "inline-block";*/
    } 
};

function matchColor2(){
  
    if( randomBtn2Num == randomShowColor) {
            
        console.log("GOOD");
        
        score.innerHTML ++; 
        
    } else {
        console.log("WRONG");
       
        /*gameContainer.style.display = "none";
        gameOverContainer.style.display = "inline-block";*/
    }
};

function matchColor3(){
    if(randomBtn1Num != randomShowColor && randomBtn2Num != randomShowColor){
        console.log("GOOD");
        
        score.innerHTML ++;
        
    } else {
        console.log("WRONG");
        /*gameContainer.style.display = "none";
        gameOverContainer.style.display = "inline-block";*/
    } 
};


/*Finish startGame*/  
};
```

```css
/*Main Styles*/

body {
    background-image: url()
}

h4 {
    color: #2626e6;
}


/*Main Container Styles*/

#main_container {
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}



/*Start Container Styles*/

#start_container {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    top: 20px;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 10px black;
}

#start_container button {

}

/*Game Container Styles*/

#game_container {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    top: 20px;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 10px black;
}

.second_level{
     transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.third_level{
     transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

/*Score Container*/

#score_container {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    top: -40px;
    margin-left: -5px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 10px black;
}

#score_container #score {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 30px;
    width: 80px;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}

/*Level Container*/

#time_container {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    top: -40px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 10px black;
}

#time_container #time {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 30px;
    width: 80px;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}


/*Random Show Color Style*/

#show_color{
    margin-top: 50px;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: 800;
}


/*Random Colors Classes*/

.random_color0{
    color: green;
}

.random_color1{
    color: red;
}

.random_color2{
    color: yellow;
}

.random_color3{
    color: blue;
}

.random_color4{
    color: orange;
}

.random_color5{
    color: purple;
}

/*Buttons Container Styles*/

#game_container #buttons_container {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top: 120px;
    border-top: 1px solid white;
    padding-top: 30px;
    
}

/*Buttons Style*/

#buttons_container button {
    height: 40px;
    width: 150px;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 800;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    margin: 3px;
}

#buttons_container button:focus{
    outline: 0;
}

#buttons_container button:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}

/*Game Over Container*/

#game_over_container {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    top: 20px;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 10px black;
}
```

```html
<div id="main_container">
        
       <!--  <div id="start_container">
            <button id="start_game">PLAY GAME</button>
        </div> -->

        <div id="score_container">
            <h4>SCORE:</h4>
                <div id="score">0</div>
        </div>
        
        <div id="game_container">
            <div id="show_color_container">

                <div id="show_color"></div>
                
            </div>

            <div id="buttons_container">

                <button class="btn_select" id="btn1">ONE</button>
                <button class="btn_select" id="btn2">TWO</button>
                <button class="btn_select" id="btn3">NEXT</button>

            </div>
            
        </div>
        
        <div id="game_over_container">
                <h2 id="game_over">GAME OVER</h2>
        </div>
            
       
        
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside `openTheGame()` you're using `setInterval` which calls `startGame()` every 3 seconds, which in turn creates (adds) new event handlers every 3 seconds, which call your console.logs etc. Replace `setInterval` with `setTimeout`:

```
function openTheGame(){
    setTimeout(startGame, 3000);
};

openTheGame();
```

EDIT: did not thoroughly check your code, but if you need that function called every 3 seconds, then you need to move the setup of click handlers outside that function.

Comment: Hi, This problem isn't  connect with setInterval because at the beggining I called funtion after good match (without intervals) and problem was the same.

Comment: You're adding event handlers every time you call startGame() which is what is causing the quickly raising of the scores. Indeed it doesn't solve the matching, but i't fixes the score and allows you to easier figure what goes wrong. Here, added some quick fix to only add eventhandlers once: https://jsfiddle.net/jszwpns5/

Comment: Yes, thank you , the problem might be here, so I will dig deeper in this case :)